# Installing Bigquery command-line tool

Tags: command-line, google-bigquery

I tried installing Bigquery command-line tool under Linux using "easy_install bigquery" as well as manually via "python setup.py install".

I got the message "Finished processing dependencies for Bigquery." without an error.
Still, when I type "bq", I get the message "command not found".

Is there anything else to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try running the easy_install command with the `--record=log.txt` flag? It should then give you a list of the output files when it is completed in the log.txt file.

E.g.

```
$ sudo easy_install --record=log.txt --upgrade  bigquery
....
Installing bq script to /usr/local/bin
....
$ cat log.txt 
/usr/local/bin/bq
```

You might also try the --verbose option as well.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, you can try

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery
```